# Expression must be a modifiable lvalue with enums

Tags: c++, arrays, enums, lvalue

I have a terrible program in C++ when I try to assign a enum value.
The error exists when I try to assign `Wall` or `Free` etc to `sokoban.board[j,i]`.

```
bool loadLevel(ifstream &stream, tSokoban &sokoban, int level) {
    bool ok = false; 
    string levelStr, levelFile = " ", prove;
    int j = 0;
    levelStr = "Level " + to_string(level);
    while (levelFile != levelStr && EOF) {
        getline(stream, levelFile);
    }
    if (levelFile == levelStr) {
        ok = true;
        getline(stream, prove);
        sokoban.ncol = prove.size();
        while (prove != "Level " + to_string(level + 1)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < prove.size(); i++) {
                switch (prove[i]) {
                case '#':
                    sokoban.board[j, i] = Wall;
                    break;
                case ' ':
                    sokoban.board[j, i] = Free;
                    break;
                case '$':
                    sokoban.board[j, i] = Box;
                    break;
                case '.':
                    sokoban.board[j, i] = GoalFree;
                    break;
                case '@':
                    sokoban.board[j, i] = Player;
                    break;
                }
            }
            getline(stream, prove);
            j++;
        }
        sokoban.nrows = j - 1;
    }
    return ok;
}
```

It's hard to know where is the problem because these are the declarations:

```
   typedef tTile tBoard[MAX][MAX];
typedef struct {
    tBoard board;
    int nrows;
    int ncol;
    int rowPlayer;
    int colPlayer;
    int numBoxes;
    int goalBoxes;
}tSokoban;
typedef struct {
    tSokoban sokoban;
    int numMoves;
    string nFileName;
    int level;
}tGame;
```

And if I write in the code: `sokoban.board[j,i]` this error dissapeared, could anyone tell me why this error happen?

Sorry about this mess but I don't know how to use properly this task.

Comment: Instead of a clunky `switch` why not a simple lookup table using `std::map`?

Comment: @Álvaro Sánchez  It seems you mean sokoban.board[j][i]

Comment: `sokoban.board[j, i]` is not how you access a 2d array.  If you define it with `some_name[][]` you access it with `some_name[][]`.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. Where is the enum declared?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but in C++ you don't need that C-style `typedef struct { ... } name;` stuff. Just use `struct name { ... };`

Answer (score 1):

The data member

```
tBoard board;
```

has the array type `tTile[MAX][MAX]` due to the typedef

```
typedef tTile tBoard[MAX][MAX];
```

So to access an element of the two-dimensional array you should use the postfix expression like

```
sokoban.board[j][i] = Wall;
```

where the expression `sokoban.board[j][i]` yields an lvalue of type `tTile`.

As for this expression

```
sokoban.board[j, i] = Wall;
```

then there is used the comma operator in the square braces. In fact it is equivalent to

```
sokoban.board[i] = Wall;
```

The expression `sokoban.board[i]` has the one-dimensional array type `tTile[MAX]` (see the typedef above) and is not a modifiable lvalue.